# Sorting by partition key/sort key does not work

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on an IoT project where I need to read some data from a device.
I use AWS, and I'm currently working on some lambda function code. But I can't figure out how to get the last (newest) item from my database.

My database has two keys:

Partition key:
device_id (Number)

Sort key
sample_time (Number)

This is a part of the code I wrote to retrieve the newest reading from my IoT device

```
case "GET /data/newest":
        body = await dynamo
            .query({ 
              TableName: "bikelock_db",
              KeyConditionExpression: 'device_id = :id',
              ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":id": 1,
              },
              Limit: 1,
              ScanForwardIndex: false,
            })
            .promise();
        break;
```

This code however, only returns the first added item from the database.
Changing the `ScanForwardIndex: false` to true doesn't change a thing.
I thought the `Sort Key` would sort it automatically, but it does not.

Any idea what I'm missing, or why it isn't working?

Comment: Do you have an example value for `sample_time` please? If it is a Number, `ScanForwardIndex` should 100% make a difference unless you only have 1 item in the table.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, it is a number indeed. for example, the latest item in the database has as `sample_time` field with the value of: 1651506802842. Which is just an int (or how AWS calls it a 'Number'). If I execute this line: `dynamo.scan({ TableName: "bikelock_db" }).promise();` I get more than just 1 item (database has 7 items now in it to test the sorting).

Answer (score 2):

Try `ScanIndexForward` and I bet it'll work. You transposed the two words.

Comment: Oh! I didn’t even notice that +1

Comment: How incredibly stupid of me... I'm programming in AWS online coding enviroment, so autofill or correcting doesn't work. Guess I typed it over the wrong way. Thanks a lot for noticing it! @ErmiyaEskandary, thank you to for helping me!